No sound on Ubuntu 22.04, Macmini4,1 (mid-2010)
I am trying to get an audio output from a Mac Mini 4,1 (mid-2010) running Ubuntu server 22.04 with a minimal Gnome desktop environment. In particular I want to get sound over the HDMI output.
In the settings app I can select

HDMI / DisplayPort3 - Built-in Audio
Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio
Speakers - Built-in Audio

but none work. I have checked that output levels are reasonable using alsamixer and that the speakers are not muted.
The output of sudo alsa-info --upload is here.
aplay --list-devices gives
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: CS4206 Analog [CS4206 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 1: CS4206 Digital [CS4206 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

And finally, running lspci outputs:
00:00.0 Host bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 HOST Bridge (rev a1)
00:00.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 Memory Controller (rev a1)
00:01.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d6d (rev a1)
00:01.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d6e (rev a1)
00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d6f (rev a1)
00:01.3 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d70 (rev a1)
00:02.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d71 (rev a1)
00:02.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d72 (rev a1)
00:03.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
00:03.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 Memory Controller (rev a1)
00:03.2 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 SMBus (rev a1)
00:03.3 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 Memory Controller (rev a1)
00:03.4 Co-processor: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 Co-Processor (rev a1)
00:04.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev a1)
00:04.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller (rev a2)
00:06.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev a1)
00:06.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller (rev a2)
00:08.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
00:0a.0 SATA controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 SATA Controller (AHCI mode) (rev a2)
00:0b.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d75 (rev a1)
00:0e.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d9a (rev a1)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d9b (rev a1)
00:16.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0d9b (rev a1)
00:17.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Texas Instruments XIO2213A/B/XIO2221 PCI Express to PCI Bridge [Cheetah Express] (rev 01)
02:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments XIO2213A/B/XIO2221 IEEE-1394b OHCI Controller [Cheetah Express] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
04:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 [GeForce 320M] (rev a2)

Any help or suggetion is greatly appreciated. Here are some general questions:

Given that I started with an Ubuntu server installation and added a desktop environment afterwards, do I need to setup something manually to get audio running?
Is any setup specific to the Mac Mini hardware required?

